# Redirect specific Url variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My site used to generate URLs like this:

```
/data.php?s=1432862823&type=basic
```

I have modified the program so the new URLs generated are:

```
/d.php?s=1432862823&t=basic
```

Since some people have bookmarked the old URLs I want to write a Rewrite rule that will get them to the new url.

I've not this so far:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^/data\.php$"  "/d.php"
```

but I can't figure out how to account for the variables.

Comment: Yes, use a rewrite/redirect. IIS: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969(v=ws.10).aspx Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: Thank you, I am using apache and read the document you sent. From the above example would something like this be correct: `code`RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^/data\.php?member=$"  "/d.php?m=" `code`

Comment: Update your question with the code you've written.

Comment: Take a look here, http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([^&]+)&type=([^&]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^data.php$ /d.php?s=%1&t=%2 [NC,R,L]
```

This will  externally redirect a request for :

```
/data.php?s=foo&type=bar
```

to

```
/d.php?s=foo&t=bar
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much this worked like a charm. 
Just one slight change I noticed I had to make. The type variable has two values "basic" or "pro". I have changed basic to b and pro to p. 
Please could you tell me how to incorporate this into the rewrite.
so in other words /data.php?s=1432862823&type=basic will have to become /d.php?s=1432862823&t=b

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I do apologise, I only noticed now that you have changed the `type` parameter to `t`. As such, this solution will not fit your needs, unless for a URI where the query string parameters do not change. I'm leaving this answer here so that others may learn from it - you'll be surprised how many people don't know that the query string is automatically transferred to the new destination. Starkeen's answer, therefore, is the correct answer.

---

You could follow Starkeen's solution, which specifically checks for the query string and explicitly adds it to `d.php`. Alternatively, for simplicity, you could just use this:

```bsh
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteRule ^data.php$ /d.php [R=302,L]
```

The query string will automatically be transferred from `data.php` to `d.php`, and you will be redirected accordingly.

To make the redirect permanent and cached by browsers and search engines, change `302` to `301`.